# Include School Technical Project in CV for Grad Application

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv, undergraduate

I am applying for Electrical engineering field graduate studies recently. In my school, I have done several technical projects. (I have already participated in some research project and put them under the section "research experience").

The question is that, grad schools are often looking for research potential, but my technical projects are usually too about technical implementation (such as building a small magnetic control car). I am wondering if it is suitable to put them in my CV for grad school application?

Answer (score 1):

If a project is related to your field of study, and if the supervisor(s) of the project is writing a letter of recommendation for you, by all means include it. If you simply did the project, but nobody else mentions it (in a supporting letter, for example), you might still include it, depending on how significant **you** feel the project was.